# Messy SQL question, how would we go about fixing this?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, clean-up

Noticed this old question the other day on Stack Overflow: [Is a View faster than a simple Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query)

The answer marked correct is a pretty confusing thesis, which has umpteen votes.

Somehow a question about views has become a rather long discussion about indexed views (which is a feature most people do not know about or use).

How would I go about fixing up this messy mess?

I already tried improving [BradC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439056/is-a-view-faster-than-a-simple-query/439678#439678) and upvoting it.

Comment: Brittingham's answer reads mainly like "Stop downvoting me. Microsoft said it was good, so it must be good."

Comment: @random: have you taken the time to read through the entire argumentation? That is **not** what he is saying.

Comment: @Sam Saffron: you have the right to dissagree but if the majority of SO'ers and the OP agree on it being the most helpfull answer, then so it is. I agree with you it that the question doesn't ask about indexed views per se but the whole point of SO is to help one another learning new things. In that sense, I consider the OP's question answered and he learned how to leverage views to increase performance.

Comment: @Lieven Stopped reading when the answer went with, "At least three people have voted me down on this one" (that's cruft that he's tied right into his answer). **There was too much italicised.** Eyes actually bleed sawdust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up after my own mess (I asked the question). Retraced my steps and noticed I screwed up: the answer I marked as answer evolved into a confusing blob.

BradC's answer has got a much higher information/noise ratio and is now marked as answer.

Thanks for slapping me silly.

Answer (score 2):

You are already doing the right thing. Improving BradC's answer and upvoting it.

I'm not using indexed views, so I do not know, if Brittingham is correct. But the answer "Yes" is plain wrong. If his thesis is correct it must be "No, but there are indexed views..." like BradC did.

If the thesis is correct, your question boils down to: Editing the accepted answer or voting it down? In the spirit of SO: edit it!

If the thesis is confusing as you said: downvote it!